# Complex prime factorization into Gaussian integers?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, algorithms, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

Consider a set of complex numbers such that $z=a+ib$ such that $a$ and $ b$ is an integer.

Naturally the product of two set elements is another element of the set. Now, let us try to determine the factorization of $z_3$ using:

$$z_1 z_2 = z_3$$

### Method $1$

Take the modulus

$$\implies |z_3|^2 = |z_1|^2 |z_2|^2 $$

Using prime factorization of $|z_3|^2$ we can guess the prime factors of $|z_1|^2$ and $|z_2|^2$ and hence, we will have many cases of $|z_1|^2$ and $|z_2|^2$ depending on the number of prime factors.

Then one (or more) of the cases will be resolvable into $|z_i|^2 = \Re(z_i)^2 + \Im(z_i)^2$ such that the real $ z_{i.R} $ and imaginary part $ z_{i,I} $ of $z_i$ is an integer (where $i = 1$ or $2$) out of those solutions we will see which ones satisfy $z_1 z_2 =z_3$

### Example $1$

Let $z_3 = -6 + 17i \implies |z_3|^2 = 325 = 5^2 \times 13$

We can decompose this into $ |z_1|^2 = 5 $ and $ |z_2|^2 = 5 \times 13 $ or $ |z_1|^2 = 25 $ and $ |z_2|^2 = 13 $

We note $5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$ and $13 =  2^2 + 3^2$

Hence, using hit and trail the numbers are: $ z_1 = 2+3i$ and $z_2 = 3+4i$

### Method $2$

We consider:

$$ z_1 = a +ib$$
$$ z_2 = c + id$$
$$ z_3 = e + if$$

$$\implies |z_1|^2(c+id) = (e+if)(a-ib)$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts:

$$ |z_1|^2 c + i |z_1|^2 d  =  (ae +fb) + i (fa - be)$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts:

$$|z_1|^2 =\frac{(ae+fb)}{c} = \frac{fa - be}{d}$$

$$\implies cd (a^2 +b^2)^2 = (ae + fb)(fa - be) $$

Hence, we can guess again using prime factorization.

### Questions

- Are there other useful methods of factorizing complex numbers?
- Are these methods known(/correct/useful)?
- Am I being funny or is there a hidden(deeper) statement about complex prime factorization statement that can be made?
- Hence we have $2$ methods to factorize $z_3$

[image]

Essentially what the picture above shows us is that the using method 1 one can convert the complex $z_3$ factorization problem into a sum of squares and a real prime factorization problem(s). However using method $2$ it is only a real prime factorization problem(s). Is it possible to somehow use this to convert a sum of squares problem as a prime factorization problem?

Comment: Duplicate of a question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269810/whats-a-nice-method-to-factor-gaussian-integers . More results from this search : https://www.google.com/search?q=factoring++gaussian+integers

Comment: @EthanBolker I can't seem to find the $2$nd method ...

Comment: The second link is just the search I used to find the first one. There may be other useful stuff there - you have to browse to see.

Comment: [This might be helpful for small numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Gaussian_integer_factorizations)

Answer (score 4):

Lets think about [Gaussian integer :](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKx--18vXXAhVL0mMKHWk0Cs4QFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGaussian_integer&usg=AOvVaw3Md_EM898-NYxHHdCgfdm0)  $\Bbb{Z}[i]=\{a+ib : a,b\in\Bbb{Z}\}.$
This is a ring under usual complex number addition and multiplication and here prime numbers are   (up to multiplication by $i$ )

> $1+i$
>   primes of $\Bbb{Z}$ with the form $4n+3,$
>   $a+ib$ and $a-ib$ with $a^2+b^2$ is a prime of the form $4n+1.$

For example: $90$ has the prime factorization $3^2(1+i)(1-i)(2+i)(2-i).$ We can use this factorization to find all the representations $90$ as a sum of two squares as $$90=3^2(1^2+1^2)(1^2+2^2).$$

To find the prime factorization in $z\in\Bbb{Z}[i]$ :
First find $|z|.$ If this is a prime in $\Bbb{Z}$ of the form $4n+3,$ then $z$ is already a prime. Otherwise look at the prime factorization of $|z|$ in $\Bbb{Z}.$

For example: Consider $1+8i$ which has $|1+8i|=5\times 13$ and $5=2^2+1^2=(2+i)(2-i)$ and $13=2^2+3^2=(2+3i)(2-3i)$ now using those factorizations, we can find out that $$1+8i=(2+i)(2+3i).$$

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer the OP's question: that asks for an efficient method to for expressing a Gaussian integer as a sum of squares.

Comment: @Bumblebee Thanks for your answer ... A quick survey seems everyone prefers method $1$ over method $2$. But they both seem to be equally fast any idea why?

Comment: @Ethan Bolker The OP **does not** want to express a Gaussian integer as a sum of squares.

Comment: @ProfessorVector You're right. But this still doesn't answer the question about factoring Gaussian integers.

Comment: @AnantSaxena: I think because method 1 is a systematic way to do this factorization. And there we have a ring structure on Gaussian integers. So people have a better understanding over that than the other methods

Comment: @ProfessorVector What the OP doesn't know yet, but is willing to know, is that any non-zero $a+ib\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ factors uniquely as $a+ib = i^k (1+i)^m \prod_{j=1}^n p_j \prod_{j=1}^l \pi_j^{e_j}$ where $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and $\pi_j = c+id, c^2+c^2$ is prime $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$. To achieve this, we need to factorize $a^2+b^2= \prod_{j=1}^N q_j^{d_j}$, then factorize each $q_j \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ in $q_j = \pi\overline{\pi}$